# Play Video on video

Tags: video, overlay

How can we overlay a video over another video so that they can run in sync.

I have tried using javascript but both are not playing simultaneously.

Comment: Add some more details of your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>HTML5 Video Effects</title>
</head>
<body>
      <video id="video-source" controls autoplay preload  width="500"  style="position: absolute; left:0;">
         <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
      </video>   
   <video id="video-source2" controls  autoplay preload width="500"  style="position: absolute; opacity:0.5; left:0;">
         <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
      </video>     
</body>
</html>
```

you can't control video1 because video2 catch the mouse over event, so you need to write some js code to control it.

Answer (score 0):

Without implementing some javascript code you will not find a proper solution.
A trivial solution would be to start both videos almost simultaneously. Setting the autostart attribute in both videos is on possibility, but it will fail as soon a video takes more time for loading.

```
var vid1 = document.getElementById("myVideo1");
var vid2 = document.getElementById("myVideo2");
vid1.play();
vid2.play();
```

If you think a synchronization is necessary that you have to decide which video determines the playback. As a result it as a master - slave dependency. Then you can listen on the timeupdate event of the master and correct the playback position of the slave:

```
vid1.ontimeupdate = function() { sync() }; // listen to the master video

function sync() {
  vid2.currentTime = vid1.currentTime; // correct the slave video
}
```

In case both videos include audio tracks the resulting sound can be interupted. Thus, you can sync both videos in a certain intervall, e.g. every 5 seconds:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval( sync, 5000); // 5 seconds

function sync() {
  vid2.currentTime = vid1.currentTime; // correct the slave video
}
```

To avoid further interruption you can check, whether the playback position of both videos differs too much. In the following example the videos only get synchronized, if the playback differes for more than half a second.

```
function sync() {
 if( Math.abs( vid2.currentTime - vid1.currentTime ) > 0.500 ){
  vid2.currentTime = vid1.currentTime; // correct the slave video
 }
}
```